# Local optimization of parameters in a Coupled Non-Linear System

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, modeling

I have a system of differential equations :

$\frac{dX}{dt} = (0.8+0.4c_{1})X-(0.007+0.006c_{2})XY$ and

$\frac{dY}{dt} = (0.048+0.004c_{3})XY-(0.4+0.2c_{4})Y$

where $0\le c_{i}\le1$.

Varying $c_{i}$ gives me an envelope of solutions for both $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$. My goal is to find the combination of $c_{i}$ which gives the upper and lower limits of my solution.

Taking $c_{i}$ as discrete points between 0 and 1 with step size 0.1, I used the following code to obtain a solution, and managed to plot it.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == (0.8 + 0.4 c1) x[t] - (0.007 + 0.006 c2) x[t] y[t],y'[t] == (0.0048 + 0.0004 c3) x[t] y[t] - (0.4 + 0.2 c4) y[t], x[0] == 200, y[0] == 80}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}]
xt = Flatten[Evaluate[Table[x[c1, c2, c3, c4][t] /. sol, {c1, 0, 1, 0.1}, {c2, 0, 1,0.1}, {c3, 0, 1, 0.1}, {c4, 0, 1, 0.1}]]];
mat = Table[Table[Evaluate[xt[[a]]], {t, 0, 25, 0.01}], {a,Range[Length[xt]]}];
l = Min /@ Transpose[mat];
m = Max /@ Transpose[mat];
ind = Range[0, 25, 0.01];
lupd = Transpose[{ind, l}];
mupd = Transpose[{ind, m}];
ListLinePlot[{lupd, mupd},GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> {600, 300}]
```

The plot for $X(t)$ came as
[image: plot]
The plot for $Y(t)$ came as
[image: plot]
**Edit 3**

It is *not possible* to calculate the equation of the upper curve of the envelope obtained by varying $c_{i}$s. Hence, I reworked my question.

Consider the following code fragment

```
Plot[Evaluate@({x[1, 0, 0, 1][t], x[0, 1, 1, 1][t], x[0, 0, 0, 0][t], 
     x[0.8, 0, 0, 0.2][t]} /. sol), {t, 0, 25}]
```

This gives 4 different trajectories for $X(t)$.
[image]

Consider the line $t=12$. As it cuts the enevelope, we get a *minimum* point and a *maximum* point.

I would like the combination of $c_{i}$ that give this maximum and minimum points for $t=1,2,3,...,25$.

In my solution I used `Max` and `Min` to extract these maximum and minimum points and then plotted them. I could not get the combination of $c_{i}$ for each of these points.

Comment: Any optimization does require that you construct a merit function; that is, what exactly are you optimizing? What should be "big", and what should be "small"?

Comment: The solution of the coupled equation. $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ in this case.

Comment: How can a time-varying oscillating solution be "small"? Isn't this the lower bounds (blue) curves that you are showing on the plots?

Comment: By "small" and "big" I mean the combination of $c_{i}$ which will give the topmost solution. The blue line represents the lower solution, but I do not know which combination of $c_{i}$ produced it.

Comment: In short, you effectively want to maximize $\|X(t)\|_\infty$ and $\|Y(t)\|_\infty$ in the "upper envelope" case?

Comment: Yes. And I want to know the values of $c_{i}$ at which the maximum and minimum occur. I did it for discrete values, but I have no idea about how to do it over a specified interval.

Comment: It is possible that the $c_i$ that maximize $\|X(t)\|_\infty$ can be different from the $c_i$ that maximize $\|Y(t)\|_\infty$; what do you propose to do in that case?

Comment: That is why tried the `NMinimize` command on $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ separately. It may be possible that the $c_{i}$ are different. In that case, I want both of them in my output.

Comment: Not all the constants in the LaTeX version of the equations are the same as those in the Mathematica version of the equations.  Please edit to make them consistent.  Also, please add the code you used to plot the functions.  Thanks.

Comment: I apologise for the mismatch. Added the plot commands too. @bbgodfrey

Comment: I still think this question doesn't make sense. There is no one combination of $c_i$ that gives you the lower or higher envelope of the solution as each differential equation solved (for each collection of parameters) results in solution that oscillates with different frequency so the solutions cross each other. Consider this code `Plot[Evaluate@({x[1, 0, 0, 1][t], x[0, 1, 1, 1][t], 
     x[0, 0, 0, 0][t]} /. sol), {t, 0, 25}]`. Which is the "lower bound" of these three curves? The first, second or third? Your answer depends on which time scale you look at.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct @gpap. I have reworked the question again. Thanks for pointing out an erroneous concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, the $c_i$ do not retain the frequency of the solutions constant so the solutions cross each other and there isn't one collection of $ c_i $ that satisfies the "maximum envelope" criterion. For different integer times it's an easy application of `NMaximize`:

```
Table[NMaximize[{x[c1, c2, c3, c4][t] /. sol, 0 <= c1 <= 1, 0 <= c2 <= 1, 0 <= c3 <= 1, 0 <= c4 <= 1}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}], {t, 1, 25}]
```

which produces a solution (but doesn't always converge properly so maybe some playing around with the parameters of `NMaximize` is necessary here):

```
{{311.231, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {195.645, {c1 -> 0.851284, c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {101.746, {c1 -> 0., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {72.4078, {c1 -> 0.554206, c2 -> 1., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {86.7196, {c1 -> 0.516399, c2 -> 1., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {119.434, {c1 -> 0.783024, c2 -> 1., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {174.87, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 1., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {225.381, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0.393763, c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {312.48, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {298.507, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 0.483703}}, {289.22, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 0.0869823}}, {242.738, {c1 -> 0.536497, c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 0.}}, {206.276, {c1 -> 0., c2 -> 4.11611*10^-9, 
   c3 -> 8.75751*10^-6, c4 -> 0.}}, {143.553, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 1., 
   c3 -> 0., c4 -> 1.}}, {196.936, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 1., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {245.969, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0.331846, c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {313.172, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 1.}}, {304.824, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 0.715149}}, {298.267, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., 
   c4 -> 0.4678}}, {293.266, {c1 -> 1., c2 -> 0.0000225295, 
   c3 -> 2.52908*10^-7, c4 -> 0.262797}}, {281.43, {c1 -> 0.99607, 
   c2 -> 0.00393228, c3 -> 0.739327, 
   c4 -> 0.108152}}, {270.711, {c1 -> 0.939643, c2 -> 0.000403377, 
   c3 -> 0.999011, c4 -> 0.000087475}}, {211.763, {c1 -> 1., 
   c2 -> 0.757642, c3 -> 0., c4 -> 1.}}, {261.286, {c1 -> 1., 
   c2 -> 0.265911, c3 -> 0., c4 -> 1.}}, {313.282, {c1 -> 1., 
   c2 -> 0., c3 -> 0., c4 -> 1.}}}
```

Comment: What is the runtime for this code segment? Also, how do I tabulate this result? (I have to include of a table of $c_{i}$s for different $t$ in my report)

Comment: This took about 10sec on my computer. For making a table I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706) is relevant

Comment: I will go through the link. How do you think the increase in the number of parameters will affect the runtime?

Comment: It will increase it :) By how much depends on how many more parameters, how long a time etc.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help. Also, could you go through the code I wrote to  obtain and plot the maximum and minimum values in the graphs I attached and suggest some edits? That step takes about ~20 minutes on my system (Intel i5,4 GB RAM). Increasing the number of parameters would only take more time.

Comment: I think that is a separate question in itself but you are essentially solving a nonlinear ode system $10^4$ times to obtain the solutions for each parameter